# Factorial Program in VB.net and version issues

Tags: vb.net

I bought the book Visual Basic.net Core Reference by Francesco Balena and was hoping to learn Visual basic, but I'm already having problem on my first console code sample from the book. Do you think the book is too old and the samples are no longer compatible with today's VB.net anymore? The compiler is prompting that I'm missing Sub Main(), but the sample in Francesco's book doesn't have Sub Main()

```
Module MathFunctions 
'A public constant
Public Const DoublePI as Double = 6.2831853
'A private array
    Private factValues(169) As Double
'Return the factorial of a number in the range 0-169
    Public Function Factorial(ByVal n As Integer) As Double
'evvaluate all possible values in advance during the first call.
        If factValues(0) = 0 Then
            Dim i As Integer
            factValues(0) = 1
            For i = 1 To 169
                factValues(i) = factValues(i - 1) * CDbl(i)
            Next
        End If
'check the argument
        If n >= 0 And n <= 169 Then
'return the value in the array if argument is in range
            Factorial = factValues(n)
        Else
'raise an error otherwise
            Err.Raise(6, , "Overflow")
        End If
    End Function
      'The following code block (except End Module) is what I added to the code sample, but I'm still not getting any output from the console
    Sub Main()
     Factorial(32)
    End Sub
    End Module
```

Comment: Every .NET program needs a `Main` shared function for the OS to start the program from. You may find that the book either assumes it or mentions it in passing early on.

Comment: I tried doing Sub Main() Factorial(32) End Sub, but the console hasn't outputted anything

Comment: Create a new console application and add this code into a _new_ file. The default template will have a correct declaration of a `Main` `Function` (not `Sub`)

Comment: The default declares the Main in a Sub: `Module Module1

    Sub Main()

    End Sub

End Module`

Comment: Did you build the project again?

Comment: yes i have, Im only getting _Press any key to continue . . ._ from the console

Comment: Then things are working OK. You didn't _output_ anything in your program...

Comment: I'm so sorry, is it common for authors to leave out the Sub Main() in programming books?

Comment: It is. Since it is _required_ and books have limited amount of space for code examples, they choose to leave it out of most code listings. They do normally at least mention the requirement.

Comment: I've now added `Console.WriteLine(Factorial(37))` to the `Main`, but my output is always `0` no matter what number i put in the factorial function...

Comment: i double checked, this is coming straight from the code sample =( can you tell where the bug is? I don't quite understand the  `Factorial = factValues(n)` is that where the problem is?

Comment: you are right, thank you. I added the return value because the code sample did not have it in the function. this too is common in programming books?

Comment: No. Code samples should work. Possibly the author didn't debug it properly (looks like it was written by a former VB6 programmer) - that, unfortunately is very common. Try looking on the web for book errata that may mention this.

Comment: so VB6 did not require a return value for functions?

Comment: The style in VB6 was `Factorial = factValues(n)` - returning a value from a function was done by assigning to the function name within the function.

Comment: does that make it a bad book to learn VB? this book was recommended to be by a friend, and he says francesco is good at teaching vb.

Comment: Dunno. Never read it so can't comment on that.

Comment: how do we make the program return `Err.Raise(6, , "Overflow")`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11186/discussion-between-oded-and-user133466)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is executing absolutely fine.

What you are probably expecting is to see the returned value from your function - however, you have not output it anywhere.

If you change your `Main` to the following, you will see a result:

```
Sub Main()
 Console.WriteLine(Factorial(32))
End Sub
```